# Delete some lines from string

Tags: swift, string

I have a string:

```
first line
second line

first line

first line
second line

first line
```

How can I remove `secondlines` from this string? `Secondlines` are always different, `firsts` too. Only division between them is `\n\n`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import Foundation

let string = "first line\n"
           + "second line\n"
           + "\n"
           + "first line\n"
           + "\n"
           + "first line\n"
           + "second line\n"
           + "\n"
           + "first line"

func removeSecondLines1(string: String) -> String {
    let tokens = string.components(separatedBy: "\n")

    var deletedString = tokens[0]
    for i in 1...tokens.count - 1 {
        if tokens[i] == "" || tokens[i - 1] == "" {
            deletedString = deletedString + "\n" + tokens[i]
        }
    }
    return deletedString
}

func removeSecondLines2(string: String) -> String {
    let tokens = string.components(separatedBy: "\n\n")

    var deletedTokens = [String]()
    for token in tokens {
        deletedTokens.append(token.components(separatedBy: "\n")[0])
    }
    return deletedTokens.joined(separator: "\n\n")
}

print(removeSecondLines1(string: string))
print(removeSecondLines2(string: string))
```

Both will output

```
first line

first line

first line

first line
```

Comment: @aaisataev I add another answer might be more elegant

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun a solution with Regular Expression:

```
let string = "first line\nsecond line\n\nfirst line\n\nfirst line\nsecond line\n\nfirst line"

let pattern = "\\n[^\\n]+\\n\n"
let result = string.replacingOccurrences(of: pattern, with: "\n\n", options: .regularExpression)
print(result)
```